# Make a specific cell read-only in MSExcel

Tags: vba, excel

I need to convert a cell read-only if certain conditions apply.

**Example:**

If in cell **L** there is a list of options (e.g. Android or Java) and if the user selects one of the options (e.g. android) then cell **M** should be read-only.

If user selects the other option (e.g. Java) then cell **M** should not be read  only, since **M** also contains a list of options that are related to the selected user option (e.g. Java types).

Comment: If Range("L" & p).Value = Android Then.....
    Range("M" & p).Select....
   Selection.Locked = True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for cells **L1** and **M1**

Enter the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim L As Range, M As Range
    Set L = Range("L1")
    Set M = Range("M1")
    If Intersect(Target, L) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    M.Locked = False
    If L.Value = "Android" Then
        M.Locked = True
    End If
    ActiveSheet.Protect
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

Macros must be enabled for this to work!

**EDIT1:**

in the worksheet:

[image]

and then in the *VBA* Window:

[image]

**EDIT#2:**

Here is a version that will handle a **block** of cells:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim L As Range, M As Range
    Set L = Range("L1:L10")
    Set M = Range("M1")
    If Intersect(Target, L) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    For p = 1 To 10
        Range("M" & p).Locked = False
        If Range("L" & p).Value = "Android" Then
            Range("M" & p).Locked = True
        End If
    Next p
    ActiveSheet.Protect
End Sub
```

Comment: If Intersect(Target, L) Is Nothing Then '--this line causing error object required

Comment: Make sure the code is in the **worksheet code area!**

Comment: Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Dim A As Range, B As Range
    Set A = Range("A1")
    Set B = Range("B1")
    If Intersect(Target, A) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    M.Locked = False
    If A.Value = "Android" Then
        B.Locked = True
    End If
    ActiveSheet.Protect
End Sub I ahve pasted the code in button_click event

Comment: I have to create a macro and insert this code inside it ?? I am not getting where to paste this code I am new to macro please tell me in detail if possible

Comment: But its making entire worksheet protected I dont want that just that particular cell should be readonly

Comment: But it causing entire sheet to be protected, I want to make only single cell as readonly

Comment: But this code is not working for Entire column ... For p = 1 To 10...
    Set L = Range("L" & p)....
    Set M = Range("M" & p)

Comment: The code is designed for only a single cell pair...but it could be modified.  how much of columns **L & M** should be checked??

Comment: I have changes the code to  For p = 1 To 10
    'If Range("L" & p).Value = Android
    Set L = Range("L" & p)
    Set M = Range("M" & p) Isn't it fyn

Comment: U have uploaded the same code. Please check it out once